# Disabling default null value ASP select list

Tags: asp-classic, selectlist, disabled-input, selectlistitem

I am trying to disable the default value for an asp select list, the default value being the string "null".

I want this to remain as the default, but when the user has selected another item in the select list to disable it as a selectable option.

The ASP code for the select list is below:

```
Response.Write "<Select name=""PersonID" & temporary.Fields("EventID") & class=""SelectText"" style=""width:100%"">" & vbCrLf &_
"<Option value=""NULL""></Option>"
```

Comment: Why do you need a NULL option in your select list in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would need to do this, usually you convert the empty value to null in your backend script if needed, or you can use something like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to do this client-side, hoping that your browser has javascript enabled:

```
$("select").change(function(e){ 
    $("option[value='NULL']:first",this).remove(); 
});
```

This will remove the first null option in your select list on change.  If you need more help with javascript/jquery, you should tag your questions as so.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Zee Tee's answer, you could read the value on post back and determine its value...

```html
<select id="personId" name="personId<%=eventId%>" class="selectText">
    <option value="-1">-- Please select a value --</option>
    <option value="1">......</option>
</select>
```

...and the postback code...

```vbs
Dim personId, failForm
personId = Request.Form("PersonId")
failForm = (personId = -1)
```